# How to make portable library of Zxing.Net to use with mvvmcross?

Tags: xamarin.android, zxing, mvvmcross

I would like to scan bar code,  Zxing.Net look pretty good but I need to have a portable version so that I can use in my project (monodroid/WP/IOS/MVVMCROSS). I will use this portable version in ViewModel.

Comment: Sorry my question lacks precision, I tried nothing, I just want to know how to build a portable class library with the project Zxing.net. There is nothing special to do to make it work with mvvmcross ?

Comment: In my honest opinion... try something, then if you hit problems ask... here's a starter for you https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=how+to+make+a+portable+class+library

Comment: There's also the question of ZXing.Net or are you trying ZXing.Net.Mobile, the later of which will never be a PCL since it deals with UI for each platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added a project file and some other small changes which are needed to build ZXing.Net for PCL. You can get it from the source code repository at codeplex. You have to build your own version because at the moment there is no pre built binary. Next version will include it.
The restriction of the PCL version is that you have to deal with RGB data. You can't use platform specific classes like Bitmap, WriteableBitmap, BitmapSource or Color32.

Comment: What is the name of your project file ?

Comment: Here is the full path:
https://zxingnet.svn.codeplex.com/svn/trunk/Source/lib/zxing.portable.csproj

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is still relevant or needed but I couldn't find a ZXing plug for MvvmCross so I ended up building one: https://github.com/asednev/MvvmCross.Plugins.ZXing. Android only for now. More to come.